# DataFrame only has last item after construction

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The dataframe that I have constructed will only return the last item in the list.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
def stockStat():
    for heading in doc(".mw-headline:contains('S&P 500 Component Stocks')").parent("h2"):
        rows = pq(heading).next("table tr")
        for row in rows:
           tds = pq(row).find("td")

        cik = [tds.eq(7).text()]
        ticker = [tds.eq(0).text()]

    d = {'CIK': cik, 'TICKER' : ticker}

    temps = pd.DataFrame(d)

    print(temps)

stockStat()
```

The list which comes from parsed data is passed into the dataframe, but the dataframe will only recognize the last item.

## Outcome

```
0  0001555280    ZTS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are looping through the rows and binding `tds` to what you want at each row, then the for loop ends and `tds` corresponds to the last row. You then make lists with just one element for `cik` and `ticker`.

Try the following instead:

```
    cik = []
    ticker = []
    for row in rows:
       tds = pq(row).find("td")
       cik.append(tds.eq(7).text())
       ticker.append(tds.eq(0).text())
```

Comment: Excellent! I know its a noobie mistake, but I have to start learning somewhere.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are overwriting `cik` and `ticker` in each iteration of your loop. So you'll only have the last item once the loop has finished.

Be sure to `append` to the lists instead.